# Laravel 5.3 and Angular 2 Installation

Tags: angular, installation, laravel-5.3

Does anyone know how to setup Angular 2 with laravel 5.3? so far i have tried this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dohhsLSbkYA)
But i can't make it work with the final release of angular 2. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you checked this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-with-angular-2-1?

Answer (score 0):

Here the repo in github;  https://github.com/eliyas5044/laravel5.3-angular2;

1. First clone it or download it.
2. Following this Command;

   - composer install
   - Rename .env.example to .env
   - php artisan key:generate
   - npm install
   - Go node_modules>elixer-typescript>index.js and comment this line
     //.pipe($.concat(paths.output.name))
   - gulp or php artisan serve

This is initial setup of Angular 2 with Laravel 5.3. You can check it in detail here; https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-with-angular-2-1

Comment: Everytime you run npm install , the index.js under node_modules>elixer-typescript will be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

Even if you had success following that tutorial it is still mediocre solution for integrating Angular into Laravel.
It requires editing file in **node_modules** and for me that is unacceptable.

One other thing I don't get is why every solution out there puts Angular app in **resources/assets/typescript**?

Not greatest solution if you work on large scale Angular app and in a team, and what if you want to have more Angular apps integrated into single Laravel project?

Try this approach on integrating Angular with Laravel

https://github.com/toni-rmc/laravel-angular-integration

- no need to edit anything in node_modules
- Angular apps are separated within their own directory in Laravel project
- Angular routing in Laravel enabled and explained
- you work in build directory (angular_apps)  and publish your work to dist directory (public) using commands provided
- TypeScript is separated from compiled JavaScript
- watch mode supported
- browser synchronization supported
- plenty commands to make your workflow easy and enable you to concentrate on writing code for your Angular apps and not to think about build processes

I hope you find it useful.